# Back return from detail fragment to List Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a ListView that gets and shows some data from RSS.I am showing on ListView and with onClickListener I show detail of list element.There is no problem until here.But My ListView class and detail class are both Fragment.When I want to back to List fragment from detail , it is not return.How to from detail to List fragment?Here is some codes;

```
public class BlogPostsFragment extends Fragment{
```

...

```
}

public class BlogDetailFragment extends Fragment{
```

...

```
}
```

Here is the fragment transaction in Activity;

```
 private void displayView(int position) {
    fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new BlogPostsFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(drawerList.get(position));// Burada Fragment'ın titleı
                                            // veriliyor.
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        Log.e("BlogMainPageActivity",
                "Fragment oluşturulurken hata meydana geldi!");
    }
}
```

Here is the code fragment transaction;

```
vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BlogDetailFragment bdf = new BlogDetailFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", currentItem.getTitle());
            bundle.putString("description", currentItem.getDesc());
            bundle.putString("pubDate", currentItem.getPubDate());
            bundle.putString("link", currentItem.getLink());

            bdf.setArguments(bundle);

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, bdf).commit();

        }
    });
```

I begin transaction in an activity.So I am calling BlogPostsFragment from Activity.

Comment: please show the code for fragment transaction

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Try adding addToBackStack to your transaction, like this : 
beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: have you got solution on this can you plz share your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do onClick:

```
String fragmentTag = getFragmentTag();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentTransaction  fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
BlogDetailFragment bdf = (BlogDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

if(BlogDetailFragment == null) {
    bdf = new BlogDetailFragment();
    //ADD BUNDLE HERE
}
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, bdf, fragmentTag);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentTransaction = null;
```

Comment: This is a good solution but when I got back,it is loading the listview again.So parsing rss again.How to prevent this?

Comment: Post your fragment code. Are you doing the loading onResume of the fragment?

Comment: No.I am loading onCreate of the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

When you replace your list fragment with the detail fragment, you can add the list fragment to the back stack. This will put the list fragment on the top of the back stack, popping it when the user press back. Modify your code as so:

```
vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BlogDetailFragment bdf = new BlogDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("title", currentItem.getTitle());
        bundle.putString("description", currentItem.getDesc());
        bundle.putString("pubDate", currentItem.getPubDate());
        bundle.putString("link", currentItem.getLink());

        bdf.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, bdf).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
});
```

Comment: It is working now.But loading listview again every return?